# How to create unique messages to rabbitmq queue - spring-amp

Tags: spring-rabbit

I am putting a message containing string data to rabbitmq queue. 
Message publishing is called as a part of a service and the service can be called with same data (data goes to the queue) multiple times, thus chances for having duplicated data in the queue is very likely.
 We have issues with this as the consumer code is inserting this data to table where this data is primary key. Consumer will be called from 4 different nodes simultaneously thus chances for having consumers consuming same data (from different messages) can happen.

I want to know if rabbitMQ publishing has any way to avoid message duplication.

Read "define a property "x-unique-message-code" to compare them is an easy and simple way" , but don't know how to do it.

I am using spring-amqp

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is a good article from RabbitMQ about reliability: https://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html

There is a note like:

> In the event of network failure (or a node crashing), messages can be duplicated, and consumers must be prepared to handle them. If possible, the simplest way to handle this is to ensure that your consumers handle messages in an idempotent way rather than explicitly deal with deduplication.

For this purpose the message to produce can be supplied with a `messageId` property.